# How to return a row for every date in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve the sum of transactions for every date from the last 7 days from my MySQL database, but some dates don't have any transactions. How do I return a 0 for those days?

Here is the SQL query I've worked on nd tried, but this one only gives those that do have a value for those days.

```
SELECT COUNT(transaction_id) AS orders, SUM(amount) AS sales, CAST(time AS DATE) AS time FROM tbltransactions WHERE time BETWEEN CAST(? AS DATE) AND CAST(? AS DATE) GROUP BY CAST(time AS DATE) ORDER BY time ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to [generate](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fe8e0/4) the dates first, then join your data table:

```
 SELECT COUNT(transaction_id) AS orders
      , SUM(amount) AS sales
      , CAST(dates.time AS DATE) AS time 
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) + INTERVAL num DAY AS time
    FROM 
    (
       SELECT 1 AS num UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
     ) n 
  ) dates
 LEFT JOIN tbltransactions 
    ON dates.time = tbltransactions.time
 GROUP BY CAST(dates.time AS DATE) 
 ORDER BY dates.time ASC
```

[image]

here is the test data:

```
CREATE TABLE tbltransactions (
  time DATE,
  transaction_id INT,
  amount DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO tbltransactions (time, transaction_id, amount)
VALUES 
  ('2023-01-20', 1, 100.00),
  ('2023-01-21', 2, 200.00),
  ('2023-01-27', 3, 300.00),
  ('2023-01-29', 4, 400.00),
  ('2023-01-29', 5, 500.00);
```